# How can I check things between 3 lists?

Tags: c#, list, linq, unity-game-engine, except

I need some help here with my game code. It's a game about making some dishes and delivering. You need to  catch some ingredients that are spawned in the ground, when you catch it they go to your inventory.

There are 3 types of recipes, with 1, 2 and 3 ingredients. Also, the ingredients DON'T need to be in order in your inventory to complete the recipe, it should just verify if you have the right itens. If you have 3 ingredients, it should verify in the list of recipes with 3 ingredients if is there anything with these itens.

The ingredients have names and Ids.

```
public abstract class IIngredient : IItem {
    public string ingredientName;
    public int ingredientId;
}
```

The recipes are a list of IIngredient, and the recipe has a name:

```
public abstract class IRecipe {
    public List<IIngredient> ingredients;
    public string recipe_name;
}
```

And the inventory

```
public abstract class IInventory
{
    public List<IIngredient> ingredient_inventory; 
    public abstract void AddIngredient(IIngredient ingredient);
}
```

The player inventory:

```
public class PlayerInventory : IInventory
{

    public PlayerInventory()
    {
        this.ingredient_inventory = new List<IIngredient>();
    }

    public override void AddIngredient(IIngredient ingredient)
    {
        ingredient_inventory.Add(ingredient);
    }
}
```

When I deliver the item, I want to check how many itens do I have in my inventory, to know which recipes I should compare, and after, try to match my itens with all the recipes that have the same amount of ingredients. If any recipe match, I want to know who it was.

I'm using this code, but it's not working:

```
player_inventory_ingredients_id = new List<int>();
player_inventory_ingredients_name = new List<string>();

   public override void CheckRecipe(PlayerInventory playerInventory) 
    {

        foreach (IIngredient item_ingredient in playerInventory.ingredient_inventory)
        {
            player_inventory_ingredients_name.Add(item_ingredient.ingredientName);
            Debug.Log("You have " + item_ingredient.ingredientName); 
        }

        List<IRecipe> recipes_item_amount = recipes.FindAll
                      (i => i.ingredients.Count == playerInventory.ingredient_inventory.Count);



        foreach (IRecipe recipe_name in recipes_item_amount)
        {
            Debug.Log("Possible recipes are " + recipe_name.recipe_name);

            List<string> recipe_temp = new List<string>();
            IEnumerable<string> test_the_names = player_inventory_ingredients_name.Except(recipe_temp);

            foreach (IIngredient ingredients in recipe_name.ingredients)
            {
                Debug.Log(recipe_name + " ingredient is: " + ingredients);

                recipe_temp.Add(ingredients.ingredientName);
            }
        }    

}
```

The last code block, that I try to verify and check if I have the itens, don't show any result. I don't even know if the code I wrote make sense hehe

Comment: The last code block, that I try to verify and check if I have the itens, don't show any result. I don't even know if the code I wrote make sense hehe

Comment: Then you need three nested for loops 1) User 2) recipe name 3) ingredients

Comment: @GertArnold made it! thank you!

Comment: @jdweng do you mind to write it?

Comment: Where is the list of players.  I do not see where you are getting the player name from?

Comment: Actually, anyone who has a 'PlayerInventory' class, have a inventory. For now I'm testing with just one player.

Comment: I'm having logic problems with testing if the itens the player have match with any of the possible recipes

Comment: let me edit the post, and add this code so you can see

Comment: Where is the Player Name?  what is the connection between the name and PlayerInventory?

Comment: The player name doesn't matter in this case, that part of de code is solved, what is not solved is how to check if an inventory, that is a list of ingredients => *playerInventory.ingredients*  have the same itens of any recipe in *recipe_item_amount*

Comment: You need three nested for loops 1) Recipe 2) Recipe Ingredients 3) Player Ingredients.  then check if loop 2 and 3 match.

Comment: I'll add a possible answer, could you check please if it is what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < recipes_item_amount.Count; i++)
{
    int item_ok=0;

    for (int f = 0; f < recipes_item_amount[i].ingredients.Count; f++)
    {
        if (item_ok == recipes_item_amount[i].ingredients.Count)
        {
            Debug.Log(recipes_item_amount[i].recipe_name);
        }

        for (int v = 0; v < playerInventory.ingredient_inventory.Count; v++)
        {
            if (playerInventory.ingredient_inventory[v].ingredientName == recipes_item_amount[i].ingredients[f].ingredientName)
            {
                Debug.Log("This item matchs");
                item_ok++;
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                Debug.Log("This item doesn't match");
            }
        }
    }
```

But i didn't got the recipe name, the debug just shows that:

[Debug.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECW7C.png)

Comment: Yes.  But you need to find only one match.  So before you go the the last for loop you have a variable : Boolean found = false.  Then when you get a match you set true and exit last for loop.  The "doesn't match" only occurs if found == false.

Comment: posting another answer >>>>

Answer (score 0):

Does it make sense? It doesn't show the right answers :(

```
bool found = false;

for (int i = 0; i < recipes_item_amount.Count; i++)
{           

    if (!found)
    {
        Debug.Log(recipes_item_amount[i].recipe_name);
    }

    for (int f = 0; f < recipes_item_amount[i].ingredients.Count; f++)
    {          
        for (int v = 0; v < playerInventory.ingredient_inventory.Count; v++)
        {
            if (playerInventory.ingredient_inventory[v].ingredientName == recipes_item_amount[i].ingredients[f].ingredientName)
            {
                Debug.Log("This item matchs : " + recipes_item_amount[i].ingredients[f].ingredientName);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                Debug.Log("This item doesn't match: " + recipes_item_amount[i].ingredients[f].ingredientName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I moved code around.

```
for (int i = 0; i < recipes_item_amount.Count; i++)
{

    for (int f = 0; f < recipes_item_amount[i].ingredients.Count; f++)
    {
        bool found = false;
        for (int v = 0; v < playerInventory.ingredient_inventory.Count; v++)
        {
            if (playerInventory.ingredient_inventory[v].ingredientName == recipes_item_amount[i].ingredients[f].ingredientName)
            {
                Debug.Log("This item matchs : " + recipes_item_amount[i].ingredients[f].ingredientName);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("This item doesn't match: " + recipes_item_amount[i].ingredients[f].ingredientName);
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            Debug.Log(recipes_item_amount[i].recipe_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works when I have one item in the recipe, but the recipes with 2 or 3 itens it didn't work

Comment: May be you are missing ingredients!

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it, thank you so much @jdweng for your help!

```
for (int i = 0; i < recipes_item_amount.Count; i++)
{
    int have_item = 0;

    for (int f = 0; f < recipes_item_amount[i].ingredients.Count; f++)
    {
        for (int v = 0; v < playerInventory.ingredient_inventory.Count; v++)
        {
            if (playerInventory.ingredient_inventory[v].ingredientName == recipes_item_amount[i].ingredients[f].ingredientName)
            {
                Debug.Log("This item matchs : " + recipes_item_amount[i].ingredients[f].ingredientName);
                have_item++;
                Debug.Log(have_item);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("This item doesn't match: " + recipes_item_amount[i].ingredients[f].ingredientName);
            }
        }
        if (have_item == playerInventory.ingredient_inventory.Count)
        {
            Debug.Log(recipes_item_amount[i].recipe_name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
        var ingredientIds = playerInventory.ingredient_inventory.Select(i => i.ingredientId).ToList();

        var recipiesMatchingAllTheIngredients = recipes.Where(r => r.ingredients.Count == ingredientIds.Count &&
            r.ingredients.All(i => ingredientIds.Contains(i.ingredientId)))
            .ToList();
```

Linq is awesome :)